# How can I draw a red circle around blobs detected in image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have the following image:

[image]

I want to achieve 3 outcomes in the output:

1. Highlight the black dots/patches in the image, with a red circular outline around them.
2. Count the number of dots/patches
3. Print the number of dots/patches overlaid on the image.

Right now, I can only count the number of dots/patches in the image and print it:

```
import cv2

## convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.imread("blue.jpg", 0)

## threshold
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## findcontours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

## filter by area
s1= 3
s2 = 20
xcnts = []
for cnt in cnts:
    if s1<cv2.contourArea(cnt) <s2:
        xcnts.append(cnt)

print("Number of dots: {}".format(len(xcnts)))
>>> Number of dots: 66
```

But I am not able to figure out how to highlight the patches on the image.

**EDIT:** Expected results for the following image:

[image]

would be this:

[image]

Comment: use `drawContours()`

Comment: Please add a second, marked-up image showing the expected results. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Edited to include an example output.

Comment: @Kristada673, the provided image will in gray-scale of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some approaches:

**1. Color Thresholding**

The idea is to convert the image to HSV format then define a lower and upper color threshold to isolate the desired color range. This results in a mask where we can find the contours on the mask with [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and draw the contours using [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours)

[image]
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Color threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 127])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original,original,mask=mask)

# Find blob contours on mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original,[c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**2. Simple Thresholding**

The idea is to threshold and obtain a binary mask. Similarly, to highlight the patches in the image, we use `cv2.drawContours()`. To determine the number of colonies, we keep a counter while iterating through the contours. Finally, to print the number of patches onto the image, we use [`cv2.putText()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin))

[image]
[image]

> Colonies: 11

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
colonies = 0
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
    colonies += 1

print("Colonies:", colonies)
cv2.putText(image, 'Colonies: {}'.format(colonies), (0, image.shape[0] - 15), \
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Color thresholding to detect the blue blobs would also work

```
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 84])
```

You can use this script to determine the HSV lower and upper color ranges

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load in image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin','image',0,179,nothing) # Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax','image',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax','image',0,255,nothing)

# Set default value for MAX HSV trackbars.
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize to check if HSV min/max value changes
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

output = image
wait_time = 33

while(1):

    # get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin','image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin','image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin','image')

    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax','image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax','image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax','image')

    # Set minimum and max HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if( (phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display output image
    cv2.imshow('image',output)

    # Wait longer to prevent freeze for videos.
    if cv2.waitKey(wait_time) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How do I highlight smaller patches instead of bigger patches? Like this for example: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39755678/66451120-9e61ab00-ea8d-11e9-8baa-ea2c9142212d.jpg

Comment: Use `cv2.contourArea()` with a minimum/maximum threshold area. If the contour passes this filter then highlight it else ignore it. Something like `maximum = 500`, `if cv2.contourArea(c) < maximum:` then highlight

Answer (score 2):

drawContours(), convexHull() or minEnclosingCircle() should work with what you want. 
Here is a tutorial from opencv that shows how to do what you want to do:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

OpenCV has a lot of great tutorials so check them first when you want to learn something new :)

Comment: This opens 2 windows, one with the original image and a tracker for the threshold, and another for the highlighted circle. I wanted it in the same window - i.e., the original image with the patches highlighted.

Comment: Just draw the circles on the original image instead of using a drawing.

Comment: `cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
cv.circle(drawing, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]), color, 2)` change drawing here to the name of your original image

Comment: This way, I get the highlights on the original image, but the tracker window is still separately appearing. How to get `cv.createTrackbar()` to create the trackbar in the same original window?

Comment: Do you _want_ the trackbar? Or did you just copy all the code in the example? To add it to your original image you use `source_window = 'Source'
cv.namedWindow(source_window)
cv.imshow(source_window, src)` and then `cv.createTrackbar('Canny thresh:', source_window, thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)` and point them to the window you want the trackbar in. To avoid the other window to appear you just avoid creating or showing it.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to have it, as different values of the threshold give different "accuracy" of the patches being highlighted - smaller value of threshold means smaller patches get highlighted too that should have been considered as part of bigger patches (which are already highlighted). And bigger threshold, of course, means some patches do not get highlighted. So, a trackbar would be nice to have, but on the same window. Without it, I have to manually run the program again and again in a hit-and-try fashion to get the optimal threshold value.

Comment: The trackbar seems like another question than the one you asked, google some tutorials about adding a trackbar to a window and follow them :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. @alkasm said, you can use `cv2.drawContours()`. So, you can add the following at the end of your code:

```
image = cv2.imread("blue.jpg")
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts,
        contourIdx = -1, 
        color = (0, 255, 0), #green
        thickness = 5)
cv2.imshow('Contours', image) 
cv2.waitKey()
```

Now, the image will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the threshold such that even the fainter dots are highlighted?

Comment: Check this [link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)... hope this is what you want :)